# Doesn't work django-localization

Tags: python, django

In settings:

```
USE_I18N = True
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware
.....

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en_US'
```

django.mo compiled and has strings translate.
I put django_language=ru in cookies and django-admin become Russian. but my strings in _() in English. 
How I can get it work?

Answer (score 0):

Are your string ins _() that are in english something that you added or is it from the default django install? If it is something you added you will need to build and compile your message files.

Have you followed these instructions?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `gettext_lazy`, not `gettext`:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Also make sure your strings aren't marked `fuzzy` in the translation file!